# How do I keep the hash associations when building permutations

Tags: ruby, permutation

UPDATE: Possible solution at the end, but certainly not performant or ideal.

I created the following method that gives me close to what I want.

```
def multi_permutations(collection)
  case collection.length
  when 1
    return collection.shift[1]
  when 0
    raise "You must pass in a multidimensional collection."
  end

  a = collection.shift[1]
  b = multi_permutations(collection)

  return_value = []
  a.each do |a_value|
    b.each do |b_value|
      return_value << [a_value] + [b_value]
    end
  end

  return return_value
end
```

When I pass in a hash with nested arrays that looks like this...

```
my_collection["item_9"]   = [152]
my_collection["item_2"]   = [139, 143, 145]
my_collection["item_13"]  = [138, 142, 150]
my_collection["item_72"]  = [137, 149, 151, 154]
my_collection["item_125"] = [140, 141]
my_collection["item_10"]  = [144, 146, 147, 148, 153]
```

I want it to create an array of hashes with all permutations that looks like this...

```
[{ "item_9": 152 }, { "item_2": 139 }, { "item_13": 138 }, { "item_72": 137 }, { "item_125": 140 }, { "item_10": 144 }]
[{ "item_9": 152 }, { "item_2": 139 }, { "item_13": 138 }, { "item_72": 137 }, { "item_125": 140 }, { "item_10": 146 }]
[{ "item_9": 152 }, { "item_2": 139 }, { "item_13": 138 }, { "item_72": 137 }, { "item_125": 140 }, { "item_10": 147 }]
[{ "item_9": 152 }, { "item_2": 139 }, { "item_13": 138 }, { "item_72": 137 }, { "item_125": 140 }, { "item_10": 148 }]
[{ "item_9": 152 }, { "item_2": 139 }, { "item_13": 138 }, { "item_72": 137 }, { "item_125": 140 }, { "item_10": 153 }]
.
.
.
[{ "item_9": 152 }, { "item_2": 145 }, { "item_13": 150 }, { "item_72": 154 }, { "item_125": 141 }, { "item_10": 144 }]
[{ "item_9": 152 }, { "item_2": 145 }, { "item_13": 150 }, { "item_72": 154 }, { "item_125": 141 }, { "item_10": 146 }]
[{ "item_9": 152 }, { "item_2": 145 }, { "item_13": 150 }, { "item_72": 154 }, { "item_125": 141 }, { "item_10": 147 }]
[{ "item_9": 152 }, { "item_2": 145 }, { "item_13": 150 }, { "item_72": 154 }, { "item_125": 141 }, { "item_10": 148 }]
[{ "item_9": 152 }, { "item_2": 145 }, { "item_13": 150 }, { "item_72": 154 }, { "item_125": 141 }, { "item_10": 153 }]
```

What this function ends up doing is close but I lose the relationships.

```
[152, [139, [138, [137, [140, 144]]]]]
[152, [139, [138, [137, [140, 146]]]]]
[152, [139, [138, [137, [140, 147]]]]]
[152, [139, [138, [137, [140, 148]]]]]
[152, [139, [138, [137, [140, 153]]]]]
.
.
.
[152, [145, [150, [154, [141, 144]]]]]
[152, [145, [150, [154, [141, 146]]]]]
[152, [145, [150, [154, [141, 147]]]]]
[152, [145, [150, [154, [141, 148]]]]]
[152, [145, [150, [154, [141, 153]]]]]
```

The relationships are very important to me.  The reason is, I plan to hydrate an object where the attrs are the keys in the hash.  I'm sure this can be done in a better way, and I'm open to suggestions.

So one possible solution I've come up with is to create a keys array then flatten the permutations and zip them together in a hash.

```
  results = []
  permutations = multi_permutations(possibilities)
  permutations.each do |permutation|
    results << Hash[keys.zip permutation.flatten!]
  end
```

This ends up giving me...

```
{"item_9"=>152, "item_2"=>145, "item_13"=>150, "item_72"=>154, "item_125"=>141, "item_10"=>146}
{"item_9"=>152, "item_2"=>145, "item_13"=>150, "item_72"=>154, "item_125"=>141, "item_10"=>147}
{"item_9"=>152, "item_2"=>145, "item_13"=>150, "item_72"=>154, "item_125"=>141, "item_10"=>148}
{"item_9"=>152, "item_2"=>145, "item_13"=>150, "item_72"=>154, "item_125"=>141, "item_10"=>153}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get your solution to run because you did not provide how to call it, so I couldn't compare the efficiency.

What do you think about this solution? (the single argument has to be a Hash of Arrays, just like your `my_collection`)

```
my_collection = {}
my_collection["item_9"]   = [152]
my_collection["item_2"]   = [139, 143, 145]
my_collection["item_13"]  = [138, 142, 150]
my_collection["item_72"]  = [137, 149, 151, 154]
my_collection["item_125"] = [140, 141]
my_collection["item_10"]  = [144, 146, 147, 148, 153]

def permutations!(input)
  input.each do |key, possibilities|
    possibilities.map!{|p| {key => p} }
  end

  digits = input.keys.map!{|key| input[key] }

  digits.shift.product(*digits)
end

results = permutations!(my_collection)
```

Please notice that this method modifies the input object because of the `map!` usage.

Comment: I placed your method in place of mine and got these results... {1=>[{1=>110}], 2=>[{2=>103}, {2=>106}, {2=>107}, {2=>108}, {2=>109}], 3=>[{3=>112}], 4=>[{4=>101}], 5=>[{5=>102}, {5=>104}, {5=>105}], 6=>[{6=>111}]}  I do have an example of how to call it at the bottom of my question.  The problem being that it doesn't create a distinct record for each permutation.  It stacks the arrays up just like mine.  :(

Comment: Hash In: {1=>[110], 2=>[103, 106, 107, 108, 109], 3=>[112], 4=>[101], 5=>[102, 104, 105], 6=>[111]}
Hash Out: {1=>[{1=>110}], 2=>[{2=>103}, {2=>106}, {2=>107}, {2=>108}, {2=>109}], 3=>[{3=>112}], 4=>[{4=>101}], 5=>[{5=>102}, {5=>104}, {5=>105}], 6=>[{6=>111}]}

Comment: I've updated my answer. Please run it isolated from your stuff to avoid side-effects.

Comment: This is working just like I asked for.  I asked for the wrong thing.  :(  Thanks though!  I wanted the output like I had in the final section and I just realized that what I asked for is exactly what you gave me.  Giving you the points for a great solution.  If you have time I'd love some help changing the format to what I meant to ask for.  ie. The format that is below... "This ends up giving me..."

Comment: Either way you got me headed in the right direction I think.  So now I'm just going to see if I can make sense of this method.  thanks!

Comment: Found that I can do this:  new_results = results.reduce({}, :merge)