# Converting Array of Array of Hashes to Array of Hashes

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, multidimensional-array, permutation

I have an array of arrays of hashes.

```
items = 
[{ "item_9": 152 }, { "item_2": 139 }, { "item_13": 138 }, { "item_72": 137 }, { "item_125": 140 }, { "item_10": 144 }]
[{ "item_9": 152 }, { "item_2": 139 }, { "item_13": 138 }, { "item_72": 137 }, { "item_125": 140 }, { "item_10": 146 }]
[{ "item_9": 152 }, { "item_2": 139 }, { "item_13": 138 }, { "item_72": 137 }, { "item_125": 140 }, { "item_10": 147 }]
[{ "item_9": 152 }, { "item_2": 139 }, { "item_13": 138 }, { "item_72": 137 }, { "item_125": 140 }, { "item_10": 148 }]
[{ "item_9": 152 }, { "item_2": 139 }, { "item_13": 138 }, { "item_72": 137 }, { "item_125": 140 }, { "item_10": 153 }]
.
.
.
[{ "item_9": 152 }, { "item_2": 145 }, { "item_13": 150 }, { "item_72": 154 }, { "item_125": 141 }, { "item_10": 144 }]
[{ "item_9": 152 }, { "item_2": 145 }, { "item_13": 150 }, { "item_72": 154 }, { "item_125": 141 }, { "item_10": 146 }]
[{ "item_9": 152 }, { "item_2": 145 }, { "item_13": 150 }, { "item_72": 154 }, { "item_125": 141 }, { "item_10": 147 }]
[{ "item_9": 152 }, { "item_2": 145 }, { "item_13": 150 }, { "item_72": 154 }, { "item_125": 141 }, { "item_10": 148 }]
[{ "item_9": 152 }, { "item_2": 145 }, { "item_13": 150 }, { "item_72": 154 }, { "item_125": 141 }, { "item_10": 153 }]
```

What I'd like to do is change it to be an array of hashes...

```
items =
{"item_9"=>152, "item_2"=>145, "item_13"=>150, "item_72"=>154, "item_125"=>141, "item_10"=>146}
{"item_9"=>152, "item_2"=>145, "item_13"=>150, "item_72"=>154, "item_125"=>141, "item_10"=>147}
{"item_9"=>152, "item_2"=>145, "item_13"=>150, "item_72"=>154, "item_125"=>141, "item_10"=>148}
{"item_9"=>152, "item_2"=>145, "item_13"=>150, "item_72"=>154, "item_125"=>141, "item_10"=>153}
```

I believe I can do this using...

```
items.map! { |item| item.reduce({}, :merge) }
```

However, it's not very performant.  At least it's not performant enough when you have 140million records.  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: The first I would try: `:update` instead of `:merge` for in-place updates.

Comment: It's interesting to note that using for loop does not really help anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

perhaps a bit longer but it works much quicker:

```
require 'benchmark'

items = [
  [{ item_9: 152 }, { item_2: 139 }, { item_13: 138 }, { item_72: 137 }, { item_125: 140 }, { item_10: 146 }],
  [{ item_9: 152 }, { item_2: 139 }, { item_13: 138 }, { item_72: 137 }, { item_125: 140 }, { item_10: 147 }],
  [{ item_9: 152 }, { item_2: 139 }, { item_13: 138 }, { item_72: 137 }, { item_125: 140 }, { item_10: 148 }],
  [{ item_9: 152 }, { item_2: 139 }, { item_13: 138 }, { item_72: 137 }, { item_125: 140 }, { item_10: 153 }],
  [{ item_9: 152 }, { item_2: 145 }, { item_13: 150 }, { item_72: 154 }, { item_125: 141 }, { item_10: 144 }],
  [{ item_9: 152 }, { item_2: 145 }, { item_13: 150 }, { item_72: 154 }, { item_125: 141 }, { item_10: 146 }],
  [{ item_9: 152 }, { item_2: 145 }, { item_13: 150 }, { item_72: 154 }, { item_125: 141 }, { item_10: 147 }],
]

n = 100_000
Benchmark.bm do |b|
  b.report do
    n.times do |i|
      items.map { |item| item.reduce({}, :merge) }
    end
  end
  b.report do
    n.times do |i|
      # the winer
      items.map { |item| item.reduce({}, :update) }
    end
  end
  b.report do
    n.times do |i|
      items.map { |i| i.inject({}) { |f,c| f.update c } }
    end
  end
end
```

as @tokland suggests, `item.reduce({}, :update)` is even faster:

```
   user     system      total        real
6.300000   0.080000   6.380000 (  6.386180)
1.840000   0.020000   1.860000 (  1.860073)
2.220000   0.020000   2.240000 (  2.237294)
```

thanks @tokland

Comment: Is it faster than `reduce({}, :update)`? just saying to keep it closer to the original code.

Comment: Yeah this is a very good speed up.  Processing 17million records takes ~ 243secs  Which is a lot faster than the other way.  Going to give you credit for the answer, because I think the only way to make this faster is to build the data the way I want.  But that's in my other question. Unfortunately I asked for help building it incorrectly.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13283330/how-do-i-keep-the-hash-associations-when-building-permutations

Answer (score 0):

Since performance is an issue, it might be time for `for` loops `yield`s as well as noticing interesting facts about your data, if any. For example, your data seem to have many repetitive items. Is that a rule or just a coincidence?

Comment: It's just a coincidence when generating random data sets.  I actually de-dup it before doing this.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re sure you have a two-level array (no other arrays inside the pairs) and exactly two items in each pair, then it’s faster and shorter to use this:

```
array = [['A', 'a'], ['B', 'b'], ['C', 'c']]
hash = Hash[*array.flatten]
```

For more than two-level deep arrays this will give the wrong result or even an error (for some inputs).

```
array = [['A', 'a'], ['B', 'b'], ['C', ['a', 'b', 'c']]]
hash = Hash[*array.flatten]
# => {"A"=>"a", "B"=>"b", "C"=>"a", "b"=>"c"}
```

But if you’re running Ruby 1.8.7 or greater you can pass an argument to Array#flatten and have it flatten only one level deep:

```
# on Ruby 1.8.7+
hash = Hash[*array.flatten(1)]
# => {"A"=>"a", "B"=>"b", "C"=>["a", "b", "c"]}
```